# Call object reference by value is not working as expected

Tags: java

In the code snippet below I am calling `nodeDepths(root, depth, depthSum)` and expecting updated value in `depthSum` but every time it's returning 0 to me

```
public static int nodeDepths(BinaryTree root) {
            Integer depthSum = 0;
            Integer depth = 0;
            nodeDepths(root, depth, depthSum);
            return depthSum;
    
        }
    
        public static void nodeDepths(BinaryTree root, int depth, Integer depthSum) {
            depth = depth + 1;
            depthSum = depthSum + depth;
    
            if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                return;
            }
    
            nodeDepths(root.left, depth, depthSum);
    
            nodeDepths(root.right, depth, depthSum);
    
        }
```

**Note:** I have not mentioned the problem scenario and logical part as that is not an issue. The issue I am facing is the *"depthSum reference variable not getting updated in caller method"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
depthSum = depthSum + 1
```

does not change `depthSum` object, but the binding of the local `depthSum` variable. Like any local variable updates, it will not propagate to the caller, because the caller only knows the original binding — that is why this call strategy is a subtype of call by value (where the value is the reference to an object).

In order to do what you want, you would need to do something like

```
depthSum.increment()
depthSum.add(1)
depthSum.setValue(depthSum.valueOf() + 1)
```

But unfortunately `Integer` is immutable, and no such methods exist. It is not possible to use call by object sharing strategy to update an `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks for the conceptual correction which I am doing. Can you suggest the alternative way to handle this?

Comment: Relying on mutables is frowned upon, particularly for such almost-primitive types, but you _could_ make your own `MutableInteger` that would contain an `int` that you could modify. A sounder approach is to explicitly return the return values from the function.